# VBA code updates Excel from Powerpoint text boxes, but if the PPT is open, it creates a copy of the PPT file instead of editing the existing file

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

So I have a VBA code on Excel, which when run, takes text from Power Point text boxes, and updates specific cells in the Excel file.

This works fine if I update the Power Point, close it, then open the Excel file and run the VBA. But if I have the Power Point file open while running the code, It creates a new copy of the Power Point file, instead of making changes to the existing one.

```
Sub ExtractPowerPointTextBoxes()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim pptTextBoxes As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Open PowerPoint application
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True
    
    ' Open the PowerPoint presentation
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\floor_planning_test.pptx")
    
    ' Set the worksheet to paste data
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Set the slide to the first slide
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides(1)
    
    ' Set the text boxes
    Set pptTextBoxes = pptSlide.Shapes
    
    ' Extract the data from PowerPoint and paste it into Excel
    ws.Range("A1").Value = pptTextBoxes("TextBox-1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ws.Range("A2").Value = pptTextBoxes("TextBox-2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ws.Range("A3").Value = pptTextBoxes("TextBox-3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    
    ' Set the text boxes
    Set pptTextBoxes = pptSlide.Shapes
       
    ' Clean up
    Set pptTextBoxes = Nothing
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Data extracted successfully", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `GetObject` to get the ppt App object reference
- Create a new App instance if not found
- Use a `For` loop to get the opened presentation file
- Open the ppt file if not found

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [GetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1010959)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub ExtractPowerPointTextBoxes()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    Dim pptTextBoxes As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Const PPT_FILE = "floor_planning_test.pptx"
    ' Get existing App
    Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    If pptApp is Nothing Then
        ' Open PowerPoint application
        Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        pptApp.Visible = True        
    End If
    ' Get the opened Presentation
    For Each pptPres In pptApp.Presentations
        If pptPres.Name = PPT_FILE Then Exit For
    Next
    If pptPres is Nothing Then
        ' Open the PowerPoint presentation
        Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & PPT_FILE)
    End If
    ' Set the worksheet to paste data
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Set the slide to the first slide
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides(1)
    ' Set the text boxes
    Set pptTextBoxes = pptSlide.Shapes
    ' Extract the data from PowerPoint and paste it into Excel
    ws.Range("A1").Value = pptTextBoxes("TextBox-1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ws.Range("A2").Value = pptTextBoxes("TextBox-2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ws.Range("A3").Value = pptTextBoxes("TextBox-3").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ' Set the text boxes
    Set pptTextBoxes = pptSlide.Shapes
    pptPres.Close   ' Close ppt file
    ' Clean up
    Set pptTextBoxes = Nothing
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Data extracted successfully", vbInformation
End Sub
```